# Why is the sign of terms in orthogonal polynomials always alternating?

Tags: polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

I checked some expressions of orthogonal polynomials, e.g. [Laguerre Polymonial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaguerrePolynomial.html), [Legendre Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html), [Hermite Polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html), etc. And the sign of terms in them are always alternating. For example,
$$H_8(x) = 256 x^8-3584 x^6+13440 x^4-13440 x^2+1680$$
The sign of each term is $(+~-~+~-~+)$. This seems to be true for every polynomials. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Simply being an orthognal family is of course not sufficient for such a property. For example, we might replace $H_6$ and $H_8$ with $uH_6+vH_8$ and $vH_6-uH_8$ and break the sign rule by suitably choosing $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 3):

I think this follows from the fact that all these families satisfy a three-term recurrence relation
$$
P_n(x) = (x-\alpha_{n-1}) P_{n-1}(x)-\beta_{n-2} P_{n-2}(x)
$$

Comment: See also https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aml.2005.10.023.

Comment: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both positive, then there seems to be a competition between $P_{n-1}(x)$ and $P_{n-2}(x)$, the second term may inverse the sign?

Answer (score 3):

Once we have a [Rodrigues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula)-like formula (encoding *a particular* choice of an orthogonal base) the alternating signs are a pretty straightforward consequence. For instance, in the Legendre case
$$ P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n.\tag{1}$$
The binomial expansion of $(x^2-1)^n$ has alternating signs: trivial. The operator $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$ does not change that, neither it does the multiplication by $\frac{1}{2^n n!}$.